# Extract lines from (oddly deliminated) txt file and write to new file with Python

Tags: python, gps

I have .txt files (one per image) that is formatted as can be seen below. However, the deliminator used in the file is very strange. I cannot figure out how to extract the information I am interested in.

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.20
File Name                       : R0010023.tiff
Directory                       : C:/gtag/wf1313
File Size                       : 46 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2016:07:07 20:57:38+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2016:07:07 20:57:38+01:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2016:07:04 21:18:17+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 4928
Image Height                    : 3264
Bits Per Sample                 : 8 8 8
Compression                     : PackBits
Photometric Interpretation      : RGB
Image Description               : 
Make                            : RICOH IMAGING COMPANY, LTD.
Camera Model Name               : GR II
Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 558 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Samples Per Pixel               : 3
Rows Per Strip                  : 51
Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 447 bytes, use -b option to extract)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : GR Firmware Ver 01.02
Modify Date                     : 2016:06:21 13:09:52
XMP Toolkit                     : Image::ExifTool 10.20
Compressed Bits Per Pixel       : 3.2
Flash Fired                     : False
Flash Function                  : False
Flash Red Eye Mode              : False
Flash Return                    : No return detection
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Copyright                       : 
Exposure Time                   : 1/1250
F Number                        : 6.3
ISO                             : 100
Sensitivity Type                : Standard Output Sensitivity
Exif Version                    : 0230
Date/Time Original              : 2016:06:21 13:09:52
Create Date                     : 2016:06:21 13:09:52
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Aperture Value                  : 6.3
Brightness Value                : 8.6
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 2.8
Metering Mode                   : Multi-segment
Light Source                    : Shade
Maker Note Type                 : Rdc
Firmware Version                : 1.02
Recording Format                : JPEG
Exposure Program                : Manual
Drive Mode                      : Single-frame
White Balance                   : Shade
White Balance Fine Tune         : 0 0
Focus Mode                      : Manual
Auto Bracketing                 : Off
Macro Mode                      : Off
Flash Mode                      : Off
Flash Exposure Comp             : 0
Manual Flash Output             : Full
Full Press Snap                 : Off
Dynamic Range Expansion         : Off
Noise Reduction                 : Weak
Image Effects                   : Standard
Vignetting                      : Off
Toning Effect                   : Off
Hue Adjust                      : Off
Focal Length                    : 18.3 mm
AF Area X Position 1            : 632
AF Area Y Position 1            : 418
AF Area X Position              : 2435
AF Area Y Position              : 1610
AF Status                       : In Focus
AF Area Mode                    : Auto
Sensor Width                    : 4928
Sensor Height                   : 3264
Cropped Image Width             : 4928
Cropped Image Height            : 3264
Wide Adapter                    : Not Attached
Color Temp Kelvin               : 0
Crop Mode 35mm                  : Off
ND Filter                       : Off
WB Bracket Shot Number          : 0
User Comment                    : 
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 4928
Exif Image Height               : 3264
Exposure Mode                   : Manual
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 28 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Contrast                        : Normal
Saturation                      : Normal
Sharpness                       : Normal
Owner Name                      : 
Serial Number                   : (00000000)14100511
Lens Info                       : 18.3mm f/2.8
Lens Make                       : RICOH IMAGING COMPANY, LTD.
Lens Model                      : GR LENS
GPS Version ID                  : 2.3.0.0
GPS Latitude Ref                : xxxx
GPS Longitude Ref               : xxxx
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Time Stamp                  : 12:09:52
GPS Img Direction Ref           : True North
GPS Img Direction               : 228.21
GPS Date Stamp                  : 2016:06:21
GPS Pitch                       : 0.79
GPS Roll                        : 0.41
PrintIM Version                 : 0300
Aperture                        : 6.3
Flash                           : Off, Did not fire
GPS Altitude                    : 91.7 m Above Sea Level
GPS Date/Time                   : 2016:06:21 12:09:52Z
GPS Latitude                    : xx deg xx' x.xx" N
GPS Longitude                   : x deg x' xx.xx" W
GPS Position                    : xx deg xx' x.xx" N, x deg x' xx.xx" W
Image Size                      : 4928x3264
Megapixels                      : 16.1
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 1.5
Shutter Speed                   : 1/1250
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.020 mm
Field Of View                   : 65.5 deg
Focal Length                    : 18.3 mm (35 mm equivalent: 28.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 2.71 m
Light Value                     : 15.6
```

If I try the following examples the following is returned,

```
sfile = open("R001.txt", "r")
sfile.readline(1)
```

'E'

```
sfile.readline(2)
```

'xi'

```
sfile.readline(3)
```

'fTo'

```
sfile.readline(4)
```

'ol V'

```
sfile.readline(5)
```

'ersio'

And so on and so forth. Could anyone enlighten me as to how to deal with a file of this type?

What I am interested in is extracting several lines,

File Name GPS Longitude, GPS Latitude etcetera.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Regards
Joel

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Thank you so much for the comments! I am really grateful!

I have the following now,

```
import glob
file_list = glob.glob("*.txt")

for file_ in file_list:
    saved_lines = []
    sfile = open(file_, "r")
    lines = sfile.readlines() #array of all lines
    for line in lines:
        for text in ['File Name', 'GPS Longitude', 'GPS Latitude', 'GPS Altitude', 'GPS Img Direction', 'GPS Pitch', 'GPS Roll']:
            if text in line:
                saved_lines.append(line)
    parsed = "".join(saved_lines) #reassemble the file
    with open("parsed.txt", "a") as ofile: #write your output
        ofile.write(parsed)

dict={}
sfile = open("R0010022.txt", "r")
list = sfile.readlines()
for i in list:
    dict[i.split(':')[0]] = ''.join(i.split(':')[1:])
```

The challenge I am facing now is that I need to format the data in te following format (to be able to import it in a program I would like to use),

```
"#image latitude    longitude   altitude    yaw pitch   roll"
"R001.JPG   xx.xxxx y.yyyy  zzz.zz  319.9   8.2 -2.1"
"R002.JPG   xx.xxxx y.yyyy  zzz.zz  319.4   10.1    3.6"
```

So one line per image with the data above.

Creating a dictionary as above is a good first step (I think). The dictionary is difficult to call, though, as each member of the dictionary has a different number of spaces after the member name. That is, File Name-----------------------:... etcetera.

Is there a way to look up a member, excluding the spaces?

If I can do that it should be possible to group each image, and then write each group to separate lines in a .csv or .txt file.

Comment: You don't see the pattern here?  Did you try calling `readline` with no argument?

Comment: Do you know what is this encoding of the file ?

Comment: @Scott Hunter
If I call 'readline()' I get the following,

_'ExifTool Version Number         : 10.20\n'_

Comment: @Xander
I am not sure how to check the encoding of the file. Could you explain how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling `readline(1)` you're recieving 1 character of the first line. When you're calling `readline(2)` you're recieving the **next** 2 characters of the first line and so on. When you hit a new line it will continue on the second line.

Call `readline()` with no arguments and you'll get the whole line.

If you want several lines you could use `readlines()`, which return a list of strings with all lines in the text file. Then you can extract them as you do with a normal list.

For more information read the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: Thank you!

Brilliantly simple. I had used 'readlines()' at some point, but it did not dawn to me to write it to a specified list.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

As Scott Hunter pointed out (obliquely), you're not reading the file line by line. If you checked out the docs for readline, you'd see that calling it with no argument reads a whole line, while calling it with a numeric argument reads that many *bytes*, not *lines*.

So  `sfile.readline(1)` reads the first byte of the file (`'E'`) and increments the pointer to that point. `sfile.readline(2)` then takes over from that point and reads the next two bytes (`'xi'`).

And so on from there.

Instead, you probably want to do something like this:

```
saved_lines = []
sfile = open("R001.txt", "r")
lines = sfile.readlines() #array of all lines
for line in lines:
    for text in ['File Name', 'GPS Longitude', 'GPS Latitude']:
        if text in line:
            saved_lines.append(line)
parsed = "".join(saved_lines) #reassemble the file
with open("R001_PARSED.txt", "w") as ofile: #write your output
    ofile.write(parsed)
```

Comment: "Oblique" is my middle name!

Comment: Try using the .rstrip() method on your keys. `dict[i.split(':')[0]] = ''.join(i.split(':')[1:])` becomes `dict[i.split(':')[0].rstrip()] = ''.join(i.split(':')[1:])`. .rstrip() (when called with no arguments) removes all trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

It is delimited by new lines.

Try `sfile.readlines()`

Then to get the File Name, you should turn that into a dictionary. So loop through each item of the list you made:

```
dict={}

for i in list:
    dict[i.split(':')[0]] = ''.join(i.split(':')[1:])}
```

or if you always know which line the File Name is on, just use `list[X]`.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it! I have updated the question now with the help of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,
Open your file

```
    File = opem("R001.txt", "r")
```

and then read in the data into a list,

```
    lstGPSData = File.readlines()
```

and then use the split function to get into different lines and then you can use the index if you'd like to access each line

```
    For data in lstGPSData:
        lstValues = data.split(":")
        title = String(lstValue[0])
        value = String(lstValue[1])
```

Then again, if you get to put a comma (`,`) at the end of each line, you can change the split parameter to:

```
     lstValues = data.split(",")
```

And then you won't need to access them individually

If you need more, check this out [GIS Programming](http://geospatialtraining.com/file-handling-with-python-for-gis-programmers/)

Comment: Hope its not a really big file.  (its EXIF, so it shouldn't be.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will play quite a bit with GPS data so that site looks like useful!

I did not fully get your code to work, though (probably due to me being a newbie...).

This is what I wrote,
'
sfile = open("R001.txt", "r")

title=[]
value=[]

lstGPSData = sfile.readlines()
for data in lstGPSData:
 lstValues = data.split(":")
 title = str(lstValues[0])
 value = str(lstValues[1])'

If I call title I get _Light Value_, and if I call value I get _15.6\n_. But I haven't figured out how to call the rest of the values (titles and values) yet.